# How to leave space on top of logo

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

**No space between image logo and menu although i assign margin-top:20px ?**

**actually i need to show full logo as you see logo cutting**

logo problem

[image: I need leave small space between logo image and menu]

my fiddle work as below :

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedsa/z2pmwsnr/

i need to modify fiddle to leave space between logo image and menu .

**image logo**

http://www.mediafire.com/view/qd5otyc1w9yv5e9/logo.png

**my code**

```
ul {
    border-top: 4px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */

}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li i{

  color:white;
}
.w3ls_header_middle {
    padding: 0 0;
     padding-top:30px

}
.agileits_logo{
    float:right;
    margin-right:0em;
    margin-top:20px



}
```

Comment: Add `padding-top` to `.agileits_logo` would make it right. But I don't suggest you to use `float:right`.

Comment: thank you for reply i add padding-top:30px; to .agileits_logo

Comment: but also nothing changed please help me

Comment: same problem exist